# using arithmetic ops, cubic root, and rationals to re-express complex number

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, rational-numbers

I was asked to re-express the following number:

$$
z=e^{2\pi i/7}=\mathrm{cis}\left(2\pi/7\right)
$$
using only numbers from ℚ, arithmetic operations and the cubic root operation.

I tried to follow the suggested solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397046/write-complex-number-using-rational-numbers-square-root-and-arithmetic-operatio?noredirect=1#2397059) which I think it needs a minor modification, but unfortunately I'm stuck.

Any help, or a direction is welcomed.

Comment: do you mean $$\cos \left( 2/7\,\pi \right) +i\sin \left( 2/7\,\pi \right) $$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Are you happy with cube roots of complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z^7=1$, $z\neq1$, and $z^7-1=(z-1)(z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+1+1)$, $z$ is such that $z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+1+1=0$. Let $w=z+\frac1z$. Then\begin{align*}z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+1+1=0&\iff z^3+z^2+z+1+\frac1z+\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{z^3}=0\\&\iff w^3+w^2-2w-1=0.\end{align*}You can solve this equation using Cardano's formula and then solve the quadratic equation $z+\frac1z=w$.

Comment: After I find the values of w, how should I continue?

Comment: @JayMar As I wrote: you solve the equation $z+\frac1z=w$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have found the values of w, but I can't figure out how to solve the equation. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JayMar $z+\frac1z=w\iff z^2+1=wz\iff z^2-wz+1=0$. This is a quadratic equation.